# Slow wifi on laptop for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

After reading through a dozen online questions similar to mine own, I have decided to post a question myself.

I have a **Fujitsu AH531**, granted its not the newest laptop. I've had the laptop for 2 years now, and have had no problems with internet connection before.

Suddenly about 2 months ago, using wifi at home become slow and annoying. My other devices using wifi are absolutely fine, along side my housemates can also connect and have a normal
appropriate speed.

I use my laptop in various environments, work/libraries/friends houses and the internet connection is normal, its just within my own house.

Now, with this all in mind, I presume nothing is wrong hardware wise. I thought there may be a software issue - I cleaned the laptop and reinstalled with the recovery
discs given when I bought the laptop the OS **Windows 7** again - I have checked all driver updates and windows updates are running and up to date.
Can anyone give advice?

Additional information - I have Virgin internet - so I cannot dabble around with the router.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First plug in to the internet directly with an either net cable and see what gives.

If that doesn't work, then it's your internet feed.

If that works much better then swap out the WiFi router and see what that gives.  (You don't have to replace your WiFi, just go to a friend's house.)

If that works, then replace our router.  If not it's in your laptop.  Try a add on usb air interface (and disable the native radio).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots and lots of things that can make a wifi connection work slower.

One is interference, so if you can track down a device that you purchased 2 months ago that might be causing radio interference, then you could try turning that off and see if it helps your issue.